# Call Back Of Custom Delegate with share Object is not working

Tags: ios

My Custom Delegate (With Share Object) call back is not working? I pasted the code below ...

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UserLocation.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () @end
@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)fetchLocation:(id)sender{
    UserLocation *obj = [UserLocation new];
    [[UserLocation LocationObject] FetchLocation];
}

@end
```

UserLocation.h  (Custom Delegate File)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol UserLocationDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)userLocationCallBack;

@end

@interface UserLocation : NSObject <UserLocationDelegate>
{
    // Delegate to respond back
}

+ (UserLocation *) LocationObject;

+ (void)removeSharedHelper;

- (void)FetchLocation;

@property (nonatomic,strong)   id<UserLocationDelegate>UserLocationDelegate;

@end
```

UserLocation.m

```
#import "UserLocation.h"

@implementation UserLocation

static UserLocation * _sharedActivityObject;

+ (UserLocation *) LocationObject
{
    if(_sharedActivityObject != nil){
        return _sharedActivityObject;
    }
    _sharedActivityObject = [[UserLocation alloc] init];
    [_sharedActivityObject initializeActivityView];

    return _sharedActivityObject;
}

+ (void)removeSharedHelper {
    if (_sharedActivityObject != nil) {
        _sharedActivityObject = nil;
    }
}

-(void)initializeActivityView{

}

- (void)FetchLocation{
    [_UserLocationDelegate userLocationCallBack];
}

-(void)userLocationCallBack
{
    NSLog(@"Good");
}

@end
```

What mistake did I do?

Comment: Where are you making your Viewcontroller to be delegate of UserLocation?

Comment: There is a lot wrong - you are miss-using the two patterns you try to use pretty badly: singletons and delegation.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made your viewController to be delegate of UserLocation among the many other things wrong with your code. Anyways, addressing the issue at hand, Adjust your code in ViewController.h as per following (I have added comments for each step):

```
@interface ViewController () <UserLocationDelegate> //Make your VC adopt delegate of UserLocation
@end
  @implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)fetchLocation:(id)sender{
UserLocation *obj = [UserLocation new];
obj.delegate = self; //Set your VC to be delegate of UserLocation
[obj FetchLocation]; //Call the method on obj instance
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
//Add delegate method to your VC
-(void)userLocationCallBack
{
//Your code here will run when delegate is fired.
}
```

Also you don't need implementation of `-(void)userLocationCallBack` in UserLocation.m. When you call delegate method, it will look for implementation of that method in the VC which is the delegate of UserLocation. Learn about delegates in a very interesting way [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm). Also see [apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) on it to clear your concepts. Also Learn about Design patterns at this highly recommended [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns).

Adding up, as recommended sagely by trojanfoe and I quote:

> "If this is the only use of the delegate then it's unnecessary in this
>   case; if all that's being done is create instance > call method on
>   instance > get something back, then returning an object is enough. If
>   the delegate can be called at any time then I would expect it to be an
>   instance variable, not a local variable."

Comment: OK so what's happening to `obj` when `fetchLocation:` returns?

Comment: @trojanfoe Shouldn't you be asking that question from the OP? I am not the one who decides why he has to throw a delegate call then and what is the delegate method supposed to do when it is fired? This only explains how he can throw a delegate call in Vc from Userlocation. According to him, it will just print "good" and do nothing with obj or anything else.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for pointing it out. there were so many things wrong there i forgot he was calling the singleton instance. I have edited it to call the method from obj instance.

Comment: OK, that looks better, however it doesn't feel quite right.  If this is the only use of the delegate then you should point out that it's unnecessary in this case; if all that's being done is create instance > call method on instance > get something back, then returning an object is enough.  If the delegate can be called at any time then I would expect it to be an instance variable, not a local variable.

Comment: @trojanfoe you are right again but I am only assuming that this implementation of delegate is for testing purposes only to know that its working. Later the OP might add some relevant functionality to the delegate method. But again, that's an assumption. I will add your note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign anything to `UserLocationDelegate`. First note: use camel case for variable names (`userLocationDelegate`).

Assuming you want to assign something to the delegate you have to create some class that adopts the actual protocol `UserLocationDelegate`. I am going to assume that you want to assign a instance of the `ViewController` as delegate. Therefore you have to

- make the `ViewController` adopt `UserLocationDelegate`
- write a custom `userLocationCallBack` method
- assign the `ViewController` to the `UserLocationDelegate`

All that should look like the following:

Change the ViewController header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UserLocation.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UserLocationDelegate>
@end
```

Change the UserLocation header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol UserLocationDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)userLocationCallBack;
@end

@interface UserLocation : NSObject

+ (UserLocation *) LocationObject;
+ (void)removeSharedHelper;
- (void)fetchLocation;

@property (nonatomic,strong) id<UserLocationDelegate> userLocationDelegate;

@end
```

Change the ViewController implementation file by adding the following:

```
- (void)userLocationCallBack {
    NSLog(@"delegate called");
}
```

You additionally have to assign the delegate somewhere, the correct place would probably be the constructor of `ViewController`, but I will use the place where you actually instantiate the `UserLocation`:

```
- (IBAction)fetchLocation:(id)sender{
    UserLocation *obj = [UserLocation new];
    obj.userLocationDelegate = self;
    [obj fetchLocation];
}
```

Last but not least make use of the renamed property:

```
- (void)fetchLocation{
    [self.userLocationDelegate userLocationCallBack];
}
```

> Most important note: Read up on singletons, how to (**not**) use them and how they should be implemented correctly. You are messing it up pretty badly. Additionally read up on protocols and how they are supposed to be used. Your current code (even with above corrections) will probably not work as expected because you messed up pretty much every pattern you try to incorporate.

Answer (score 0):

Change this you are not setting delegate to self...

```
@interface ViewController ()<UserLocationDelegate> @end
  @implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)fetchLocation:(id)sender{
UserLocation *obj = [UserLocation new];
obj.delegate = self;
[[UserLocation LocationObject] FetchLocation];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)userLocationCallBack
{
    NSLog(@"Good in viewController");
}

@end
```

In UserLoaction.h

```
#import "UserLocation.h"

@implementation UserLocation

static UserLocation * _sharedActivityObject;

+ (UserLocation *) LocationObject
{

    if(_sharedActivityObject != nil){
        return _sharedActivityObject;
    }
    _sharedActivityObject = [[UserLocation alloc] init];
    [_sharedActivityObject initializeActivityView];

    return _sharedActivityObject;
}

+ (void)removeSharedHelper {
    if (_sharedActivityObject != nil) {
        _sharedActivityObject = nil;
    }
}

-(void)initializeActivityView{

}

- (void)FetchLocation{
    [self userLocationCallBack];
    [_delegate userLocationCallBack]; // this will call your userLoacationCallBack implementation in viewcontroller
}

-(void)userLocationCallBack
{
    NSLog(@"Good");
}

@end
```

Btw why do you want your callback method to be implemented in the same class. You changed the meaning of it completely by implementing it in same class. you should implement -(void)userLocationCallBack body in  viewcontroller.m file

Comment: How will this code work again? This will not work because You have not made the ViewController to be adoptive  of UserObjectDelegate. At the very least it will give you warning. Plus this answer does not add anything different  than the already posted correct answer.

Comment: Still wrong. Why are you calling `userLocationCallBack` in the `UserLocation`'s method `fetchLocation()`? Your VC is still not Adapting to delegate. You first call the method manually and then pass it to delegate which is absurd. I suggest you should clear concepts about delegates before potentially misleading others by answering in a wrong way

Comment: Well at least the Vc is delegate adaptive now, that's a relief. I would have downvoted your answer but that would be seen as self-serving as other answer on the post is mine. Please make sure you know what you are doing before answering an already answered question

Comment: And as pointed out by @trojanfoe, doing it wrong in IBAction `fetchLocation` as well. (Which was a mistake I shared as well)